# Riddle, similar to uuencode but it is not base64 either

Tags: encoding, decoding

I have to find out the following encoding where the http://imagebin.org/216644 image was encoded

```
Encoded http://imagebin.org/216644 image

UjBsR09EbGhDZ0FQQUljQUFBQUFBSHNzRFpRQUFLY3Z
BUDhBQU41NlNmL3NVTzIzblBmMzl3QUFBQUFBQUFBQU
FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQ
...
```

What i know is:
- encoding is used to transfer attachments over the internet
- it is not base64 or uuencode (but there a similarity it is also produce 'FBQ' series)

What would be the best practice to find out the encoding method ? Is there any free software which has built in encoder/decoders to play with it ?

Thanks advance.

Cs.

**UPDATE**

Since the encoded part must starts with encoded **'GIF89a'** which is here **'UjBsR09** ...
And since the encoded gif can be frequent on the internet thats why I tried to find 
**'UjBsR09'** with Google, and it found a document where the **base64Binary** encoded part starts with it.

But

Every base64 encoder translate the 'GIF89a' to '**R0lGODlh**' and not to **'UjBsR09'** i could not find out what whould be the background.

Answer (score 0):

I found the clue, it is not about mysterious encoding the image was taken by text, that why 
Before the base64 I have to convert it to ascii.(since the gif is binary)
So insted of

```
encodeddata=base64(image);
push2Net(encodeddata);
```

must use

```
encodeddata=base64(bta(image)) 
push2Net(encodeddata);
```

Where bta implementation in Javascript e.g window.bta(data)